# How to change action bar and action bar icons in fragments

Tags: android

I am creating an with app fragment,each fragment have different styles of action bar and icon how can we achieve on this fragments.

I have created action bar at MainActivity class but this action bar will display on all fragments.

I except the action bar change style and icons on each fragments

my app main activity will look like this. it have app logo at  the centre and navigation drawer in some fragments the app logo can be changed to app page name
[[image]]
The second image is my fragments so the action bar navigation drawer changed to back button and the action bar icons also

[image]

Comment: Are you implementing a custom `actionbar`?

Comment: What did you do until now to achieve this? Could you please post the code?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle an action bar that you have to set only one action bar in Main activity.

From fragment, you can access the main activity and you can change the action bar from the fragment as per your fragment. Like below :

`((MainActivity)getActivity()).ChangeActionbar();`

You can create various methods in Main activity to change action bar as per your use. SO you have to just call those methods from fragment like `ChangeActionbar()`.

But for that, you have to take care about the back press event because if you going back at that time you have to set your previous fragment action bar so the best way to handle that you have to add the code to change action bar in `onResume()` method. Because `onResume()` method call when the fragment is opened.

Hope! this will help you.

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

to change title and logo write method in main activity like below:

```
    public void fontToTitleBar(String title,int logo) {
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/av_Medium.ttf");
    title = "<font color='#ffffff'>" + title + "</font>";
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(title);
    s.setSpan(font, 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        toolbar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(String.valueOf(s), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));

    } else {
        toolbar.setTitle((Html.fromHtml(String.valueOf(s))));
    }
    toolbar.setLogo(logo);
}
```

then you can call this method  from your fragment by `getActivity()` to change title 
like:`((MainActivity) getActivity()).fontToTitleBar("title",r.drawable.icon);`

for change menu in fragment Override  `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and inflat new menu and set `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `onCreate()` method of fragment.
also you can handle click menu in fragment with `onOptionItemSelected` method .